# Determine if someone is on with flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, user-presence

I want to update a row in mysql when a user uses an application with flash. And when they exit that application, I want to change the row to reflect that the user has left. Is there a way to do this easily? Currently, I'm thinking of writing a connection manager with sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know when the application is in use is an easy task with the [applicationComplete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html#event:applicationComplete) event. The difficulty is to notice when the user exits the application, because there is no built-in event or mechanism that notifies you. So I think you are in the right direction with a connection based approach as you can compare in this question: [what is the Flash event listener when flash is exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2125830/256544)